# Linked video files in Linux/Mac OS X

Tags: video, unix, merge

I have some anime tv series with linked opening and ending.
E.g.:
Code Geass - Lelouch of the Rebellion - 01.mkv
Code Geass - Lelouch of the Rebellion - 02.mkv
Code Geass - Lelouch of the Rebellion - 03.mkv
Code Geass - Lelouch of the Rebellion - 04.mkv
Code Geass - Lelouch of the Rebellion - 05.mkv
...
Code Geass - Lelouch of the Rebellion - Ending.mkv
Code Geass - Lelouch of the Rebellion - Opening.mkv

In windows I can use [KMPlayer](http://www.kmplayer.com/) with Haali Media Splitter, but I do not have windows at home - there is OS X on my laptop and Ubuntu on desktop.

Is there any way to see assembled video without physical merge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [this message](http://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=626224#p626224) to patch (it's a very small patch, just a gcc optimization change) and build a mplayer with linking support.